# How to fix cmake error: cannot ouput executables to output file specified by COPY_FILE

Tags: python, makefile, cmake, openai-gym

I am trying to install python gym-retro library which uses cmake to build Unix Makefiles. However I am getting following errors during the process:
I am running on Windows 10 x64. Python 3.6.3 and Gym-Retro 0.6.0
CmakeErrorList:

```
Detecting C compiler ABI info failed to compile with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/PROGRA~2/CODEBL~1/make.exe" "cmTC_fc586/fast"
Starting cbp2make rev.147...

Using default configuration.


Cannot copy output executable
  ''
to destination specified by COPY_FILE:
  'C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/3.12.2/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin'
Unable to find the executable at any of:
  C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/cmTC_fc586.exe
  C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_fc586.exe
  C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Development/cmTC_fc586.exe


Detecting C [-std=c11] compiler features failed to compile with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/PROGRA~2/CODEBL~1/make.exe" "cmTC_9e0fb/fast"
Starting cbp2make rev.147...

Using default configuration.


Cannot copy output executable
  ''
to destination specified by COPY_FILE:
  'C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/feature_tests.bin'
Unable to find the executable at any of:
  C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/cmTC_9e0fb.exe
  C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_9e0fb.exe
  C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Development/cmTC_9e0fb.exe


Detecting CXX compiler ABI info failed to compile with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/PROGRA~2/CODEBL~1/make.exe" "cmTC_318a9/fast"
Starting cbp2make rev.147...

Using default configuration.


Cannot copy output executable
  ''
to destination specified by COPY_FILE:
  'C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/3.12.2/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_CXX.bin'
Unable to find the executable at any of:
  C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/cmTC_318a9.exe
  C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_318a9.exe
  C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Development/cmTC_318a9.exe


Detecting CXX [-std=c++1z] compiler features failed to compile with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/PROGRA~2/CODEBL~1/make.exe" "cmTC_aeefc/fast"
Starting cbp2make rev.147...

Using default configuration.


Cannot copy output executable
  ''
to destination specified by COPY_FILE:
  'C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/feature_tests.bin'
Unable to find the executable at any of:
  C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/cmTC_aeefc.exe
  C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_aeefc.exe
  C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Development/cmTC_aeefc.exe
```

CMakeOutput:

```
The system is: Windows - 10.0.17134 - AMD64
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
Build flags:
Id flags:  

The output was:
0


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.exe"

The C compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/3.12.2/CompilerIdC/a.exe"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/c++.exe
Build flags:
Id flags:  

The output was:
0


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.exe"

The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/3.12.2/CompilerIdCXX/a.exe"

Determining if the C compiler works passed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/PROGRA~2/CODEBL~1/make.exe" "cmTC_b7619/fast"
Starting cbp2make rev.147...

Using default configuration.



Determining if the CXX compiler works passed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Git/gym-retro/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/PROGRA~2/CODEBL~1/make.exe" "cmTC_1bba6/fast"
Starting cbp2make rev.147...

Using default configuration.
```

Powershell Log after running pip3 install gym-retro:
[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/kfcNpNRb)

I have no idea why this is happening, I have tried reinstalling MinGW and CMake or ran pip3 install as admin but that didn't work.

Comment: From Review: Please avoid using links and paste the relevant part of your log into the body of your question. Also, could you please explain to us, what do you mean with "Need to enter a code block to please stack exchange's formatting gods." in your question?

Comment: When you link something from `pastebin.com`, You need to add some code too. Maybe that's why he did that

Comment: Suggestion from [Google Groups "vrjuggler-questions"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vrjuggler-questions/ea3btI5Xuig) : "I'd try upgrading at least to cmake 3.0.2 and make sure you've started up vc10 at least once after installing cmake."

Comment: I am using cmake 3.12. Will vc14 work? And to start it should I just run cl.exe or am I missing something?